# Setting PySpark executor.memory and executor.core within Jupyter Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am initializing PySpark from within a Jupyter Notebook as follows:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
#
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("PySpark-testing-app").setMaster("yarn")
conf = (conf.set("deploy-mode","client")
       .set("spark.driver.memory","20g")
       .set("spark.executor.memory","20g")
       .set("spark.driver.cores","4")
       .set("spark.num.executors","6")
       .set("spark.executor.cores","4"))

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)
```

However, when I launch YARN GUI and look into "RUNNING Applications" I see my session being allocated with 1 container, 1 vCPU, and 1GB of RAM, i.e. the default values!
Can I get the desired, passing values as listed above?

Answer (score 5):

Jupyter notebook will launch the pyspark with yarn-client mode, the driver memory and some configs cannot be setted with class 'sparkConf'. you must set it in command line.

Take a look at official [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark.driver.memory)'s explains at memory's setting:

Note: In client mode, this config must not be set through the `SparkConf` directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the `--driver-memory command` line option or in your default properties file.

there is another way that can make it.

```python
import os
memory = '20g'
pyspark_submit_args = ' --driver-memory ' + memory + ' pyspark-shell'
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = pyspark_submit_args
```

So, other config should be taked with same way like above.

Answer (score 0):

Execute

```
    %%configure -f
{
    "driverMemory" : "20G",
    "executorMemory": "20G"
}
```

On the top of all cells (before Spark initializes)